# How to get all configurable options of a configurable product including "Out of Stock" status in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product

I am using this code which is return all configurable options array excluding "Out of Stock" product option.

```
$data = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($_product);
```

So, It works fine when all simple products are In the stock of a configurable product but if any simple products are "Out of stock" then this product configurable option not returning this function.

**How can I get all configurable options array of a configurable product?**

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below may be it will help

```
$this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product, null);
```